# How to get call object methods in ListView onClickListener?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, orientation, onitemselectedlistener

I'm a relatively new programmer. I'm making a ListView, and when one of the items is clicked, two or three separate TextViews (depending on the orientation) should change to one of the variables included in the object "Flick." Assuming I've already set up the methods (.getDirector() returns director) in a separate file, how would I call the method in the OnItemClickListener of the ListView? Also, there should be a feature to remove items by clicking on a button, but it resets when the orientation changes; how should I deal with this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listPort;
    ListView listLand;
    ArrayList<Flick> flicks;
    TextView description;
    TextView year;
    TextView director;
    TextView rating;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listPort = findViewById(R.id.listPort);
        listLand = findViewById(R.id.listPort);
        description = findViewById(R.id.description);
        year = findViewById(R.id.year);
        director = findViewById(R.id.director);
        flicks = new ArrayList<>();
        flicks.add(new Flick("Wizard of Oz", "Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer", "VARIOUS","1939", "", "98"));
        flicks.add(new Flick("Star Wars", "LucasFilm", "George Lucas", "1977","","93"));
        flicks.add(new Flick("Psycho","Paramount", "Alfred Hitchcock", "1960", "", "97"));
        flicks.add(new Flick("King Kong", "RKO Pictures", "Merian C. Cooper & Ernest B. Schoedsack", "1933", "", "98"));
        flicks.add(new Flick("2001: A Space Odyssey", "Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer", "Stanley Kubrick", "1968", "", "93"));
        flicks.add(new Flick("Citizen Kane", "RKO Pictures", "Orson Welles", "1941", "", "100"));
        flicks.add(new Flick("Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs", "Walt Disney Pictures", "VARIOUS", "1937", "","98"));
        flicks.add(new Flick("Casablanca", "Warner Bros.", "Michael Curtiz", "1942", "", "97"));
        flicks.add(new Flick("The Godfather", "Paramount", "Francis Ford Coppola", "1972", "", "98"));
        flicks.add(new Flick("Jaws", "Universal", "Steven Spielberg", "1975", "", "97"));

        final CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_layout, flicks);
        if(listPort != null)
            listPort.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        else
            listLand.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        listPort.setClickable(true);
        listPort.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    description.setText(flicks.get(position).getThoughts());
                    year.setText("Year Released: " + flicks.get(position).getYear());
                    director.setText("Director: " + flicks.get(position).getDirector());
                    rating.setText("Rating"  + flicks.get(position).getRating());
                    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


        });
    }




    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Flick>
    {
        Context context;
        int resource;
        List<Flick> list;

        public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Flick> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            this.context=context;
            this.resource=resource;
            list = objects;
        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View adapterView=layoutInflater.inflate(resource,null);


            TextView title = adapterView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            ImageView imageView=adapterView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            Button remove=adapterView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            title.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());
            switch(list.get(position).getStudio())
            {
                case "Warner Bros.":
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.warnerbros);
                    break;
                case "Paramount":
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.paramount);
                    break;
                case "Universal":
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.universal);
                    break;
                case "LucasFilm":
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lucasfilm);
                    break;
                case "RKO Pictures":
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rko);
                    break;
                case "Walt Disney Pictures":
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.disney);
                    break;
                case "Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer":
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mgm);
                    break;
            }
            remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    list.remove(position);
                    flicks.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    final View adapterView=layoutInflater.inflate(resource,null);
                }
            });




            return adapterView;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I understood but you simply don't call the "OnItemClickListener" method, it is called by the system when you click on the item. You only have to set the listener telling it what it should do. 
For the second question, when orientation changes the whole activity is destroyed and rebuilt, so basically it starts from scratch. You have to save relevant data eg in the instanceState and then reinitialize the UI using those data. I suggest you having a look here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: No, I meant calling the methods of the Object class (they're all string variables, I only need an example)

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `OnItemClickListener` for a while.

In `getView()` method of your `Adaptor` class, you can get any Flick object that you want from your list as like this:

```
Flick flick = (Flick) list.get(position);
String director = flick.getDirector();
```

You can set this `String` at any of `TextView`s in your list row.

```
TextView title = .....
title.setText(director);
```

So basically, `getView()` method is responsible for ***each*** Flick object you have in your list.

Comment: But the project requires that the user be able to select the item so that the TextViews separate from the ListView display additional information.

Comment: Where are you planning to place your TextViews? In another Activity or in same Activity as ListView? Please provide more details or project logic so we can look into and suggest.